# Not a member of Product with Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization

I waiting for multiple future response:

```
val futureResult =
      for{
      futureEmployee    <- this.getEmployeeById(effortConsulting.sObject.createdById)
      futureForCompany  <- this.getCompanyById(effortConsulting.sObject.forCompany)
      futureFromCompany <- this.getCompanyById(effortConsulting.sObject.fromCompany)
    } yield List(futureEmployee, futureForCompany, futureFromCompany)

futureResult onComplete {
      case Success(futureResponse) => {
    println(futureResponse)

      } [...]
```

The println outputs the following:

```
List(Employee([...]), Company([...]), Company([...]))
```

Okay, this is fine. But now i want to work with these object like this:

```
    val employee      = futureResponse(0)
    val fromCompany   = futureResponse(2)
    val forCompany    = futureResponse(1)

    println(forCompany.name)
```

This don't work. I got the following compiling error:

value name is not a member of Product with Serializable

How can i solve this and why it happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All members of a `List[A]` must have the same type `A`. So if you try to construct a `List` which contains members with different types, you actually get a `List` of their common supertype.

Because all case classes extend `Product` and `Serializable` traits, if you try to create a list containing unrelated case classes, you get a `List[Product with Serializable]`. And of course, if you then try to get an element from that list, you get a `Product with Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i have it. I have to create a tuple and not a List. Like this:

```
val futureResult =
  for{
  futureEmployee    <- this.getEmployeeById(effortConsulting.sObject.createdById)
  futureForCompany  <- this.getCompanyById(effortConsulting.sObject.forCompany)
  futureFromCompany <- this.getCompanyById(effortConsulting.sObject.fromCompany)
} yield (futureEmployee, futureForCompany, futureFromCompany)
```

Then, i can access the tuple with ._

```
    val employee      = futureResponse._1
    val fromCompany   = futureResponse._2
    val forCompany    = futureResponse._3

    println(employee)
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this?